# How to turn a List<Item> to a Map<Item, completeablefuture<xyz>>

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future, method-reference

I have an async method with a completeablefuture result:

```
public CompletableFuture<DogLater> asyncDogLater(String dogName){}
```

I have a list of dogs:

```
List<Dog> dogs;
```

Now, I want to create a map from the dog's name to the Completeablefuture:

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<DogLater>> map;
```

After checking [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/collect-stream-to-map/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v/28779227)  I was trying to do so:

```
    Map<String, CompletableFuture<DogLater>> completableFutures = dogs.stream()
            .collect( Collectors.toMap(Dog::getName,
                                       asyncDogLater(Dog::getName )));
```

But the compiler complains that the first `Dog::getName` is problematic since:

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

And the second `Dog::getName` has an error of:

> String is not a functional interface

I also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172551/static-context-cannot-access-non-static-in-collectors), but I'm still not sure how to solve this.

Comment: You need `toMap(Dog::getName, d -> asyncDogLater(d.getName()))`.

Comment: @daniu works perfectly. would you like to add it as an answer for the kudos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collectors.toMap()`s second argument needs to be of type `Function<T,R>`, in your case `Function<Dog,CompletableFuture<DogLater>>`.

`asyncDogLater(Dog::getName)` is of type `Function<Function<Dog, String>, CompletableFuture<DogLater>>` if I'm not mistaken.

You need `toMap(Dog::getName, d -> asyncDogLater(d.getName()))`.