# Wrapping and turning a single CompleteableFuture<OlderCat> to a bulk operation with result of CompleteableFuture<Map<Cat.name, OlderCat>>

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future, method-reference

We have an async method:

```
public CompletableFuture<OlderCat> asyncGetOlderCat(String catName)
```

Given a list of Cats:

```
List<Cat> cats;
```

We like to create a bulk operation that will result in a map between the cat name and its async result:

```
public CompletableFuture<Map<String, OlderCat>>
```

We also like that if an exception was thrown from the `asyncGetOlderCat`, the cat will not be added to the map.

We were following [this post](https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462721/how-to-turn-a-listitem-to-a-mapitem-completeablefuturexyz) and we came up with this code:

```
List<Cat> cats = ...

Map<String, CompletableFuture<OlderCat>> completableFutures = cats
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Cat::getName,
                    c -> asynceGetOlderCat(c.getName())
                         .exceptionally( ex -> /* null?? */  ))
            ));


CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture
            .allOf(completableFutures.values().toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()]));

return allFutures.thenApply(future -> completableFutures.keySet().stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join) ???
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(????)));
```

But it is not clear how in the `allFutures`we can get access to the cat name and how to match between the `OlderCat` & the catName.

Can it be achieved?

Comment: Why do you need `CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures`?

Comment: ...and what is the implementation of `asyncGetOlderCat`?

Comment: Something that I didn't understand from the question(correct me if I am wrong) is *map between the cat name and its async result:* to be `CompletableFuture<Map<String, OlderCat>>` and not `Map<String, CompletableFuture<OlderCat>>` or `Map<String, OlderCat>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You don't need to put an `exceptionally()` on the initial futures, but you should use `handle()` instead of `thenApply()` after the `allOf()`, because if any future fails, the `allOf()` will fail as well.

When processing the futures, you can then just filter out the failing ones from the result, and rebuild the expected map:

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<OlderCat>> completableFutures = cats
        .stream()
        .collect(toMap(Cat::getName, c -> asyncGetOlderCat(c.getName())));

CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture
        .allOf(completableFutures.values().toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));

return allFutures.handle((dummy, ex) ->
        completableFutures.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().isCompletedExceptionally())
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().join())));
```

Note that the calls to `join()` are guaranteed to be non-blocking since the `thenApply()` will only be executed after all futures are completed.

Comment: Instead of introducing `null`s, just to filter them afterwards, you can omit the `.exceptionally(ex -> null)` and change the filter step to `.filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().isCompletedExceptionally())`

Comment: @Holger Thanks, this seems better indeed. You still need to handle the exceptional completion of `allFutures` in that case though. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Or you replace `.exceptionally(ex -> null) .thenApply(__ -> ` with `.handle((__,ex) -> `.

Comment: @Holger indeed, thanks. `handle()` didn't immediately come to my mind as we aren't really handling anything but indeed it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I get it, what you need is `CompletableFuture` with all results, the code below does exactly what you need

```
public CompletableFuture<Map<String, OlderCat>> getOlderCats(List<Cat> cats) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> {
                Map<String, CompletableFuture<OlderCat>> completableFutures = cats
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Cat::getName,
                                c -> asyncGetOlderCat(c.getName())
                                        .exceptionally(ex -> {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                            // if exception happens - return null
                                            // if you don't want null - save failed ones to separate list and process them separately
                                            return null;
                                        }))
                        );

                return completableFutures
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                Map.Entry::getKey,
                                e -> e.getValue().join()
                        ));
            }
    );
}
```

What it does here - returns future, which creates more completable future inside and waits at the end.