# Checking if any element of stream is not present

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have stream of optionals. I would like to return true if any of elemeents of the stream is not present and false if all elements are present.

The code:

```
return Stream.of(a.getBestArrivalTime(),
        a.getBestDepartureTime(),
        a.getScheduledArrivalTime(),
        a.getScheduledDepartureTime())
        .anyMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

It checks whether elements are null, but it is wrong because it does not work on optionals variables. I think I need to use `Optional::isPresent`, but I could not use it because `Stream.of()` is a static method.
The fields in the stream are just chosen fields from the object.

Comment: "I think I need to use Optional::isPresent" - well, did you try it? Works for me.

Comment: what about `anyMatch(o -> !o.isPresent())`?

Comment: Looks like you cannot share your original code. So, please create a short, minimal reproducible example which mimics your code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You can write the code as you expect such as:

```
return Stream.of(a.getBestArrivalTime(), a.getBestDepartureTime(),
                 a.getScheduledArrivalTime(), a.getScheduledDepartureTime())
             .anyMatch(o -> !o.isPresent());//(Java-11) anyMatch(Optional::isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
return !Stream.of(a.getBestArrivalTime(),
    a.getBestDepartureTime(),
    a.getScheduledArrivalTime(),
    a.getScheduledDepartureTime())
    .allMatch(Optional::isPresent);
```

?

Edit: Proof of my comment about your wrong assumption of "non-static method cannot be referenced from static context.":

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Application {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        final boolean allMatch = !Stream.of(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty())
            .allMatch(Optional::isPresent);
        System.out.println(allMatch);
    }
}
```

Comment: It needs to encounter all elements of the Stream. Practically fine in this case, but in general streams are unbounded.

Comment: "non-static method cannot be referenced from static context." - has nothing to do with this, sorry

Comment: Maybe simply add a minimal reproducible example and not only snippets of code, then we can help without speculating.

Comment: @pqa1222 you should be more specific about "it stops working". I'm quiet sure, one of the elements you put into the stream is *not* an `Optional`. As said [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174196/2711488), the error message “Non-static method cannot be referred from a static context.” appears almost always when generic types do not match, especially in the context of method references. `javac` just #?@X when is should report the actual error (Eclipse isn't much better, it just produces different, but still misleading error messages).

Comment: @daniu all match operations of the Stream API are lazy. `allMatch` stops when it encounters the first non-matching element.

Comment: @pqa1222 you didn't include an exact error message yet. As said by Smutje, you should include more code, a reproducible example in the best case, in your question. Add the exact error message and try with command line `javac` to see whether you get a different error message.