# Assigning method references to Functional Interfaces

Tags: lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

Java 8+ allows assigning method references to Functional Interfaces.

Then what is the problem with below code ([jdoodle link](https://jdoodle.com/ia/G8r)) -

```
public void newMethod(){
    
    Predicate p = String::isBlank;
    
}
```

Different from the error in jdoodle compilation, in my local ([gist link](https://gist.github.com/ramshers/faf5e3d2bb3d3d134cf21a20ed8cc9e5)) i get error:

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

But - below thing worked

```
 Predicate<String> pp = String::isBlank; //this thing works
```

Comment: fine the error messages are not clear and instead confusing.. which lead to the question. Thx for the answers. @Sweeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) - `Predicate`. The [function type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9) of a raw functional interface is:

> The function type of the raw type of a generic functional interface `I<...>` is the erasure of the function type of the generic functional interface `I<...>`.

The function type for the generic `Predicate<T>` is `(T) -> boolean` (pardon my own original syntax here), a function that takes in a `T` and returns a `boolean`. Therefore, the function type of the raw `Predicate` is `(Object) -> boolean`, the erasure of `(T) -> boolean`.

This means that it is possible to assign `Objects::isNull` to such a raw functional interface (but you shouldn't use raw types in the first place):

```
// Objects::isNull takes an Object and returns a boolean, so this compiles
Predicate x = Objects::isNull;
```

The method reference `String::blank` only takes a `String`, not any kind of `Object`. Therefore it is not [congruent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) with the the function type `(Object) -> boolean` and hence cannot be assigned to a variable of type `Predicate`.

If `Predicate p = String::isBlank;` had worked, then you would be able to do something like `p.test(1)`. And `String::isBlank` would have to magically determine whether `1` "is blank".

The error message here is admittedly a bit confusing.

For `Predicate<String>`, the definition of its function type is different, and it has the function type `(String) -> boolean`, which the method reference `String::isBlank` is congruent to.

> The function type of a parameterized functional interface type `I<A1...An>`, where A1...An are types and the corresponding type parameters of I are P1...Pn, is derived by applying the substitution [P1:=A1, ..., Pn:=An] to the function type of the generic functional interface `I<P1...Pn>`.

Comment: fine the error messages are not clear and instead confusing.. which lead to the question. Thx for the answers. Accepting+1

Comment: the compiler giving error message: `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` is not correct. Right? Seems this is a kind of bug with compiler.

Comment: @samshers It is possible that this is unintentional, since raw types are very rarely used, and raw functional interfaces even more rarely. They might have overlooked this. Though, also because almost no one uses raw functional interfaces, they probably won't fix it.

Comment: Java compilers are indeed bad at error analysis/reporting. I [wrote it six years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174196/2711488); this specific message “Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context” often occurs when the compiler failed to determine the actual problem. Little has changed in this regard, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

`Predicate p` doesn't mean "infer the type parameters". It means you've declared a raw `Predicate`, which operates on an `Object`.

`String::isBlank` operates on a `String`. It can be used for a `Predicate<String>`, but not a raw `Predicate`.

Comment: fine the error messages are not clear and instead confusing.. which lead to the question. Thx for the answer +1